# How to open programs programmatically using file directory

Tags: c#, registry

I have been building voice applications for a while, and I want to try something different. I want to open programs without manually putting something like this in the programs into code:

```
Process.Start("notepad.exe");
```

I am wondering how you would execute a program using the file directory, for example:

```
string appPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath);
```

The reason why I want to do this is I don't know what programs the client will have on the computer system.. I have tried researching and everything I find is like how I have been programming.

So is there a way to pull the program executable and execute the program?

Full example:

```
if (speech == " ")
{
    Start.Process(Application.ExecutablePath);
}
```

or is there anyway to accomplish this?

Comment: Why is "from the registry" a requirement here? Surely a more sensible thing to do would be to examine the various shortcuts that have been installed in the start menu? I.e. those are the "entry points" that applications install to allow users to launch programs.

Comment: Well I can't ask every client that installs the program, to give me a list of there start menu.. I think it would be easier when a new program is installed it goes through the programs directory. However, for my own purpose I can manually put each program, because I know what programs I have.. Take you for example, I have no idea what programs you have on your computer. So how would I have my application recognize your applications plus the new ones you install? So this way you can just say "Open (application)"  Look at Microsoft Speech, Cortana or other voice activated programs.

Comment: You think your program is capable of scanning the registry for the correct paths to launch programs (when in fact, normally the only executable information stored in the registry is the path to the uninstaller), but you somehow believe that your program is *incapable* of searching the [start menu](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.specialfolder(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: Ok well lets look at this way.. If I have the program read the start menu.. Then how would you pull the information.. I figured I could pull the processes, if say for example I say "Open Aero" then it opens aero, a custom program I built. Then I say close aero.. you will have to have the process id.. So which would be easier? Also another way to look at it is, if I add a new app, is the program going to recognize the new app? and execute the command to open, without me having to do more coding and updates.. Look at Cortana, how she works, as well as MS Speech

Comment: Also, I am trying to build a custom algorithm. Which includes the registry as the receptor neurons. everything we do involves the registry, because its the deepest point of the tip of the iceberg.. I am not wanting an easy way out.. I am wanting to know how you program the registry. It can be done but how?   The same as the "Fn" key. Its hardware. But functions as a switch. What code is used to function the switch?

Comment: All I'll say further is - you seem to have a *deep* misunderstanding on what is and isn't stored in the registry. If you don't want to understand how Windows works, so be it. But don't be disappointed if people are unable to assist you in trying to read program information from the registry. As I previously said, the only information most applications store in the registry is uninstall information..

Comment: I figured it out... I was exactly the way I said it was. when you reference the path in the registry/file directory.. You have to point to the application execution. Which I did not code the portion that executes the application in the file directory...

Answer (score -1):

Ok, This Can be easily fixed by using the following code:

The following is how to get all exe applications
    using System.IO;
    using System.Windows.Forms;

```
string appPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath);
```

The below code is to get the running Applications
    using System.IO;
    using System.Reflection;

```
string path = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(MyClass)).CodeBase);
```

Now I can easily pull the procId with the GetProcess Method, to close the application that was open.